# I am facing an issue while deploy storage account using arm templates

Tags: json, azure, templates, arm, storage

I am facing an issue while deploy storage account using arm templates:

> Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'sneha1'
>   for type
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Common.Entities.TemplateGenericProperty`1[System.String]'
>   at line '20' and column '59' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested
>   resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource
>   name. A root resource type must have segment length one greater than
>   its resource name.

This is my template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageAccounts_sneha_name": {
            "defaultValue": "sneha,
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/sneha",
            "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccounts_sneha_name'), copyIndex(1) ) ]",
            "location": "centralus",
            "copy":{
             "Name":"rama",
             "count": 5
            },      

      "sku": {
            "name": "Standard_LRS",
            "tier": "Standard"
        },
        "kind": "StorageV2",
        "properties": {
            "networkAcls": {
                "bypass": "AzureServices",
                "virtualNetworkRules": [],
                "ipRules": [],
                "defaultAction": "Allow"
            },
            "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
            "encryption": {
                "services": {
                    "file": {
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    "blob": {
                        "enabled": true
                    }
                },
                "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
            },
            "accessTier": "Hot"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices",
        "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccounts_sneha_name'), '/default')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccounts_sneha_name'))]"
        ],

       "properties": {
            "cors": {
                "corsRules": []
            },
            "deleteRetentionPolicy": {
                "enabled": false
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
        "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccounts_sneha_name'), '/default/container1')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices', parameters('storageAccounts_sneha_name'), 'default')]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccounts_sneha_name'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "publicAccess": "Blob"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

what it says is that the resource `sneha1` name is malformed, if you can share the resource name I can help you fix it, but in a nutshell name should be 1 segment shorter than type:

```
name: "xxx",
type: "microsoft.storage/storageAccounts"
```

or like so:

```
name: "xxx/diag",
type: "microsoft.storage/storageAccounts/diagnosticSettings"
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs in case your **name** property is greater in length than **TYPE**

```
"apiVersion": "2016-12-01",
"name": "[concat(parameters('vaultName'), '/',  parameters('policyName'))]",
"type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies"
```

In above example name has two level and type has 3 level .

Example as shown below:

```
"name":"azVault/policy1"
"type":"Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be your problem, remove the sneha in type and try.

"type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/**sneha**",
"name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccounts_sneha_name'), '/copyIndex(1)' ) ]",